# C#: Read and modify settings in another application's app.config file

Tags: c#, configuration, interprocess

I have a number of applications running which communicate with each other but none of these applications have their own user interface.  I have a system console application which acts as a user interface for the system (i.e. the set of applications which all talk to each other).

I would like to be able to use the system console to read and modify the configuration of each of the non-gui apps.
Each app has an app.config file created using the Visual Studio Settings GUI.  The settings are all in application scope, which results in an app.config file which looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="ExternalConfigReceiver.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <ExternalConfigReceiver.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Conf1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>3</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Conf2" serializeAs="String">
            <value>4</value>
        </setting>
    </ExternalConfigReceiver.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I have tried using the following code to read the configuration settings:

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new   System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "PATH_TO_THE_FOLDER\\app.config";

System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fileMap, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

someVariable =  config.AppSettings.Settings["Conf1"];
someVariable2 = config.AppSettings.Settings["Conf2"];
```

However on closer inspection of the config.AppSettings object, I find that it contains no settings.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I using the wrong method to read the config file?  Is this method best for a different sort of config file?

Comment: I think you mean `Settings["Conf1"].Value`, you should be able to get something or do you get an error ?

Comment: If this happens runtime, then there will likly be no app.config file - config file will get the AppName.exe.config or whatever the name of main executable

Comment: While this is possible, I'd recommend against it - it allows one application (the console app) to break another application by messing up its configuration, and it forces the understanding of the way your individual apps are configured to be spread across at least two places. Instead, I'd recommend adding a "modify setting" message to the app, and have that message handler update the setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible to use the config file as XML and then use XPath to change values:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    XmlDocument configFile = new XmlDocument();

    configFile.Load("PathToConfigFile");

    XPathNavigator fileNavigator = configFile.CreateNavigator();

    // User recursive function to get to the correct node and set the value
    WriteValueToConfigFile(fileNavigator, pathToValue, newValue);

    configFile.Save("PathToConfigFile");

    // Commit transaction
    transactionScope.Complete();
}

private void WriteValueToConfigFile(XPathNavigator fileNavigator, string remainingPath, string newValue)
{
    string[] splittedXPath = remainingPath.Split(new[] { '/' }, 2);
    if (splittedXPath.Length == 0 || String.IsNullOrEmpty(remainingPath))
    {
        throw new Exception("Path incorrect.");
    }

    string xPathPart = splittedXPath[0];
    XPathNavigator nodeNavigator = fileNavigator.SelectSingleNode(xPathPart);

    if (splittedXPath.Length > 1)
    {
        // Recursion
        WriteValueToConfigFile(nodeNavigator, splittedXPath[1], newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        nodeNavigator.SetValue(newValue ?? String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Possible path to Conf1:

`"configuration/applicationSettings/ExternalConfigReceiver.Properties.Settings/setting[name=\"Conf1\"]/value"`

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you cant use the System.Configuration.Configuration to access config files of other applications

they are xml files and you can use the xml namspace to interact with them